# Pythonically updating a value in a string

Tags: python, regex, numbers

I have strings that may include numbers in square brackets. If they do I'd like to increment up the number in the final set of square brackets up by one.

```
old_content='Some text\t\t[1.00]\nSome other text'
```

So far i have code that does that, but doesn't feel pythonic.

```
open_indexes = [i for i, c in enumerate(old_content) if c == "["]
close_indexes = [i for i, c in enumerate(old_content) if c == "]"]
start       = old_content[:open_indexes[-1]+1]
end         = old_content[close_indexes[-1]:]
num         = old_content[open_indexes[-1]+1:close_indexes[-1]]
num         = float(num)+1
new_content =start +str(num) + end
```

Is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using regex

Using the [`sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) function of the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module, you can pass a function as the replacement:

```py
import re

old_content = 'Some text\t\t[1.00]\nSome other text[3.00]'

def add_one_to_match(match):
    num = float(match[1])
    return f"[{num + 1}]"

new_content = re.sub(r'\[([^]]*)\][^[]*$', add_one_to_match, old_content)
print(repr(new_content))
```

#### Using string functions

You can double-[`partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition) the string from the right (to take only the last occurrence):

```py
old_content = 'Some text\t\t[1.00]\nSome other text[3.00]'

start, _, end = old_content.rpartition('[')
num, _, end = end.rpartition(']')
print(repr(f"{start}[{float(num)+1}]{end}"))
```

Both ways will give:

```
'Some text\t\t[1.00]\nSome other text[4.0]'
```

Comment: That doesn't increment the first number, because of the `$` not matching before the second `[`.

Comment: The regex pattern `\[(.*?)]` with a lazy `?` quantifier will do the job for both numbers.

Comment: @mportes but OP doesn't want both. Only the last...

Comment: @mportes By the way using a negated group (`\[([^]]*)\]`) is more efficient then using a lazy quantifier

Answer (score 1):

Split the string into 3 parts: pre, number, post using [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall). Increment the number by 1, and join the parts back into a single string.

```
import re
old_content = 'Some text\t\t[1.00]\nSome other text'
matches = list(re.findall(r"(.*\[)(.*)(\].*)", old_content, re.S)[0])
matches[1] = str(float(matches[1]) + 1)
new_content = "".join(matches)
print(new_content)
# Some text               [2.0]
# Some other text
```